# WPF Desktop App read/write file permission?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, desktop-application

I'm currently writing my first WPF App and when I'm trying to save my serialized file to ANY path on the PC, I get an UnauthorizedAccessException (meaning access to the path is denied).

Here's the function:

```
 Public Shared Sub Serialize(Of T)(ByVal compression As Boolean, _
  ByVal path As String, ByVal instance As T)

    Try
        Dim fs As Stream = New FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        If compression Then fs = New GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress)

        bf.Serialize(fs, instance)
        fs.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I know that certain system folders are off limits, but it wouldn't let me save anywhere, no matter which drive I chose.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to write in system files or any other area which you dont have permission,You need to modify the appmanifest.xml in your project .

```
   <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"> 
   <security> 
    <requestedPrivileges> 
      <requestedExecutionLevel 
        level="requireAdministrator" 
        /> 
       </requestedPrivileges> 
       </security> 
     </trustInfo>
```

There are 2 more execution levels ,They are

a) highestAvailable
b) asInvoker